# problem to make csv file from android app and share it since android 12

Tags: java, android, csv

I want to make csv file and give the user the option to share the file.
i used this code that works good until android 12 that didn't give permission to save files from app.

```
          FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
          final File filePath = new 
           File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/excelFile.csv");

    try {
        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
        fileOutputStream.write(239);
        fileOutputStream.write(187);
        fileOutputStream.write(191);
        printWriter = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fileOutputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

        printWriter.println("צד" + ","
                + "קבוצה" + ','
                + "שם" + ","
                + "מס' מוזמנים" + ","
                + "נשלחה הזמנה" + ","
                + "סטטוס הגעה" + ","
                + "טלפון" + ","
                + "כתובת מייל" + ","
                + "סכום מתנה משוער" + ","
                + "הערות" + ","
                + "אירועים קשורים");


        Uri uriForFile = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".share", filePath);
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.SEND");
        intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.dir/email");
        intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.EMAIL", new String[] 
        {"ntamim2006@gmail.com"});
        intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.STREAM", uriForFile);
        intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.SUBJECT", "excelFile");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "send"));
        printWriter.flush();
        printWriter.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and i get this error:

W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/excelFile.csv: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Comment: Store the file somewhere that you can write (e.g., `getExternalFilesDir()` on `Context`), rather than cluttering up the root of external storage. Adjust your `FileProvider` settings to point to that new location.

Comment: you are awesome tnx!